# Running socket.io on Shared Hosting

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am using a shared hosting server from A2Hosting where I want to run a socket.io server (application), here is what I have done so far:

1. SSH'ed into server
2. Installed node
3. Run / started the socket.io server (application)

```js
var server = require('http').createServer(),
    io = require('socket.io')(server),
    port = 58082;

server.listen(port, my - domain - name);
```

But my client (the browser) can't connect to the server.

I have tried running the same socket.io sever (application) on a local Linux machine and I was able to successfully connect via the browser, so the issue lies in the configuration of the shared hosting server.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. The one thing missing is the integration of your socket.io application with the webserver. For that you will need a `.htaccess` file to redirect the incoming requests.

Create a `.htaccess` file in the `public_html` directory and add the snippet below. Replace the `XXXXX` with an unused port anywhere between `49152` and `65535`, those are the ones available. If your application won't start, try a different port.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:XXXXX/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:XXXXX/$1 [P,L]
```

If you need a more detailed guide / sources:

- [How to install and configure Node.js on managed hosting accounts](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts)