# Running socket.io on A2hosting VPS hosting

Tags: socket.io, webrtc, web-hosting

A2hosting seems not pass socket = io("https://localhost:45678") to the server.

I have done the following and check below article but still can't figure out.

[Running socket.io on Shared Hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45532690/running-socket-io-on-shared-hosting)

1. ssh into the server
2. go to /public_html directory
3. npm install socket.io and go to node_modules directory
4. edit server.js below and node server.js

```
const { createServer } = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const httpServer = createServer();
const io = new Server(httpServer, { cors: {
    origin: '*',
  } });

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("connection")
});

httpServer.listen(45678);

5. revise the .htaccess file in the public_html directory with
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:45678/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:45678/$1 [P,L]
</IfModule>

6. from the client side, just create php file and excute below
const socket = io("https://localhost:45678");

but the console said "Failed to load resource", it seems the request do not go to server.

7. if item 6 is changed to socket = io("https://muazkhan.com:9001/") it is ok.

I have ask A2hosting but they can check the port is open but not able to fix the problem.
Please help me. Thanks a lot.
```

Comment: the issue is fixed by following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757728/where-is-the-socket-io-client-side-js-file-located, and set client code to name of site not localhost such as io("https://xxx.cc:45678) and include the script file as <script src="https://xxx.cc:45678/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

Comment: Have you been able to figure it out? I am facing the same issue now.